# Update and delete specific marker in Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps

I am displaying the location of buses in google map where I am getting the location from the bus database table on the server. I am facing problem to delete or to update  their locations on google map since a new marker is always being created when the longitude and latitude change in the bus table. How can I delete and update specific Marker in Google Map?

I appreciate any help.

**Code:**

```
private void gotoLocation(double lat, double lng, String route_direct) {

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    final float zoom = 11;
    LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    if (lat != 0 && lng != 0 && !route_direct.isEmpty()) {
        MarkerOptions markerOpt = new MarkerOptions().title(route_direct)
                .position(ll).visible(true);

        Marker marker = map.addMarker(markerOpt);
        marker.showInfoWindow();
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, zoom);
        map.moveCamera(update);

    }

}
```

Comment: to delete marker just use marker.setMap(null);

Comment: but how to communicate with the markers on Google map since I want to delete and update specific markers?

Comment: I am not sure about android but in javascript i used Array of marker and tracked each marker by index.

Comment: if u r using different title for each marker, u can i dentify them with if(marker.getTitle).. or i think therez a method to get the marker id by marker.getId()...

Comment: @RishadAppat: Also there is a marker with the same title but `getId` is a good start thanks :)

Comment: The problem is the incoming data does not have `id` where the markers on the map have id.

Comment: What u meant by incoming data?

Comment: How many marker can be in single map do you have any restriction?

Comment: the passed data set to the `gotoLocation` method  which I am getting from the server I am asking myself whether I can use the `table_id` in this case?

Comment: @  chiragchavda.ks: in the worst case 300.

Comment: Does delete and update happens automatically or by user interaction?

Comment: they happen automatically without user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

I solved in this way. I created HashMap for markers.

Sample,

```
HashMap<String, Marker> markerlist = new HashMap<>();
markerlist.put(route_direct, yourmarker);//add marker to list
markerlist.get(route_direct);//get marker from list
```

Then in your update process, try this code

```
    if(markerlist.containsKey(route_direct)){
        Marker marker = markerlist.get(route_direct);
        //update marker
    }else{
        //add marker or do anything 
    }
```

but to use this flow, you need to have unique data for marker such as marker id.

Hope this will help you. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here we have used on our project in didTap marker delegates, We have created two functions one is Create marker and second one is delete marker code is given below in IOS swift
1.CreateMarker function call when you get Response from APIs
2.DeleteMarker call when you want to delete marker from map

```
//MARK: CreateMarker
func CreateMarker(TripLocation:[RECDATA])
{
    //let path = GMSMutablePath()
    for i in 0..<TripLocation.count
    {
        // Marker icon
        var image = UIImage(named: "ic_greenMark")
        // Get location coordinate
        let locationTujuan = CLLocation(latitude: Double(TripLocation[i].facilityLatitude ?? 0.0) , longitude: Double(TripLocation[i].facilityLongitude ?? 0.0) )
            image = UIImage(named: "ic_greenMark")
        // create marker
        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(locationTujuan.coordinate.latitude, locationTujuan.coordinate.longitude)
            // marker.title = titleMarker
        marker.icon = image
        marker.map = MapView

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude:CLLocationDegrees(TripLocation[i].facilityLatitude!), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(TripLocation[i].facilityLongitude ?? 0.0), zoom: 8)
            MapView.camera = camera
        // append marker into markers array to show all marker in map

        markers.append(marker)           
    }

}

//MARK: DeleteMarker
func DeleteMarker(marker:GMSMarker)
{
   // Create Temp Object array
   var Tempmarkers = [RECDATA]()
    //check marker is exist or not
   for obj in arrayRECDATA
    {
        let lat = Double(obj.facilityLatitude!)
        let log = Double(obj.facilityLongitude!)
        // remove marker from object array
        if marker.position.latitude != lat &&  marker.position.longitude != log
        {
           Tempmarkers.append(obj)

        }
   }
    // store temp array into original array
    arrayRECDATA = Tempmarkers
    // clean all marker and reload
    MapView.clear()
    CreateMarker(TripLocation: arrayRECDATA)

}
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

Define variable for each marker like
Marker m1;
Marker m2;
etc.

And do whatever operation on specific marker using that variable. To delete the specific marker

m1.delete ();
m2.delete ();

Something like this, you can try and let me know if you face any issue.